# Error in taylor approximation over an interval

Tags: calculus

I know how to find the remainder or error of a taylor approximation at any given point, but what if:
f(x) = 2x³ - 4x + 7 is approximated to a quadratic polynomial function at x=c. What would be the maximum error of the approximation in the interval 
|x-1|<1/4?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean using the first three terms of the Taylor series as a quadratic approximation?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, the first three terms